# Reading a JSON String?

Tags: android, arrays, json, string

I have this variable like json string i need to read it to get every value

```
 String data ={"sid":"48","name":"perla","email":"perla@gmail.com","pass":"613eb6402eb5164"};
```

i have tried to read the string with these methods:

```
String sid = data("sid");
String sid = data(0);
String sid = data[0];
```

but is no efficient

This is a string not an array string

Comment: u min u want to a parse the data and get the data

Comment: i receive from google a string coded like that but its a string and i need to read it to use on my activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have string like

`String data = "{sid:48, name:perla, email:perla@gmail.com, pass:613eb6402eb5164}";`

**You can parse it as:**

```
private void getData(String dataString) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dataString);

    String sid = jsonObject.getString("sid");
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
    String pass = jsonObject.getString("pass");

}
```

Comment: just i posted the same solution but different but i like more your answer

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution using jsonobject

```
String data ="{"sid":"48","name":"perla","email":"perla@gmail.com","pass":"613eb6402eb5164"}";

JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jobj = new JSONObject(data);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, jobj.toString());
            String order = jobj.getString("orderId");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```